# Matlab Vectorize

Tags: matlab, loops, probability, vectorization

I have a probability matrix(glcm) of size 256x256x20. I have reshaped the matrix to 
65536x20, so that I can eliminate one loop (along the 3rd dimension).

I want to do the following calculation.

```
for y = 1:256
    for x = 1:256
        if (ismember((x + y),(2:2*256))) 
            p_xplusy((x+y),:) = p_xplusy((x+y),:) + glcm(((y-1)*256+x),:);
        end
    end
end
```

So the p_xplusy will be a 511x20 matrix which each element is the sum of the diagonal of nxn sub matrix (where n belongs to 1:256) of the original 256x256x20 matrix.

This code block is making my program inefficient and I want to vectorize this loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ismember` is a rather expensive function call. Just looking at this it looks like you could replace your `if (ismember((x + y),(2:2*256)))` line with `if x+y<=2*256 && x+y>1`. What I'm suggesting isn't vectorizing but it could speed this code up a LOT.

Comment: Vectorisation is not necessarily faster in Matlab. With JIT compilation, for loops are often as fast as vectorised methods, and often scale better with less memory usage. Of course this assumes your for loop is sensibly-written, and @chessofnerd has already provided an improvement.

Comment: You said `" p_xplusy will be a 511x20"`, but it threw me an error with it, assuming `rand` values. I had to make it `rand(512,20)` to make it work. Could you clarify on this?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `if` statement is just checking whether `x+y` is less than or equal to 256, just force it to always be, and remove excess loops:

```
for y = 1:256
    for x = 1:256-y
        p_xplusy((x+y),:) = p_xplusy((x+y),:) + glcm(((y-1)*256+x),:);
    end
end
```

This should provide a noticeable speed-up to your code.

Comment: yes..thanks for this tip. The 'if' statement is not needed. Removed the 'if' and now the time is 0.29 seconds (before removing it was 2.7 seconds). Thank you very much for saving my time

Comment: Is the `-x` in the second `for` statement needed? I'm not sure its even valid (but can't test it because I don't have MATLAB on my current machine)

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by `"remove excess loops"`. If you were talking about removing `IF` conditional statement, that's not a loop.

Comment: @chessford should have been a `y`, oops! @Divakar I meant removing excess iterations I guess, doing `for x=1:256-y` not `for x=1:256` as the iterations for `x` greater than `y` were redundant and just required testing of the logical condition which was guaranteed to be false.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(2*n)` and thus improve runtime efficiency -

```
N = 256;
for k1 = 1:N
    idx_glcm = k1:N-1:N*(k1-1)+1;
    p_xplusy(k1+1,:) = p_xplusy(k1+1,:) + sum(glcm(idx_glcm,:),1);
end

for k1 = 2:N
    idx_glcm = k1*N:N-1:N*(N-1)+k1;
    p_xplusy(N+k1,:) = p_xplusy(N+k1,:) + sum(glcm(idx_glcm,:),1);
end
```

Some quick runtime tests seem to confirm our efficiency theory too.

Comment: I'm guessing `sum` is a `O(N)` method. Shouldn't that raise the loop back up to `O(n^2)`? Then again, if this is faster, then it's faster! (:

Comment: @chessofnerd I am guestimating summing many columns in one go must be cheaper than a naive for-loop-summing and also the number of cols range from 1 to Nxsqrt(2) and back from Nxsqrt(2) to 1. So, I guess It could be a little more than 2*N, but definitely lesser than N^2 :) Good points raised there though!